# PostgreSQL \COPY fails "ERROR: missing data for column "column name2""

Tags: postgresql, import

We are importing bulk data i.e millions of records.
We observed that due to a null value for a column , the import is getting failed.
Is there a way we could skip the import error when a record is missing and keep the job running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostgreSQL server `\COPY` command is very simple and just aborts on a single failure. You might think that it could do far better (I know I do), but there's a reason that the PostgreSQL codebase is so compact with respect to MySQL's (by a factor of ~ 10/1).

However, there is the (very) nice [`pgloader`](https://pgloader.io/) programme which compensates for this at the price of having to run a separate utility.

Of course, if you're good at the [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql.html) language (internal to the the server), then maybe you could explore that route - but why reinvent the wheel? Python and Perl also have internal PostgreSQL options. Then of course, there's all the languages under the sun external to the server.

From the [manual:](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgloader.html)

> ## PgLoader Reference Manual
>
> pgloader loads data from various sources into PostgreSQL. It can
>   transform the data it reads on the fly and submit raw SQL before and
>   after the loading. It uses the COPY PostgreSQL protocol to stream the
>   data into the server, and manages errors by filling a pair of
>   reject.dat and reject.log files.

which appears to be right up your alley?

The way it works is: (sorry for the [long quote](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/blob/master/docs/pgloader.rst))

TL;DR  - pgloader loads a batch (configurable) at a time. On failure, it "marks the spot", uses `\COPY` again up until that point, stops, then puts the bad record into a file and continues from bad-record + 1.

> ## Batches And Retry Behaviour
>
> To load data to PostgreSQL, pgloader uses the COPY streaming protocol.
>   While this is the faster way to load data, COPY has an important
>   drawback: as soon as PostgreSQL emits an error with any bit of data
>   sent to it, whatever the problem is, the whole data set is rejected by
>   PostgreSQL.
>
> To work around that, pgloader cuts the data into batches of 25000 rows
>   each, so that when a problem occurs it's only impacting that many rows
>   of data. Each batch is kept in memory while the COPY streaming
>   happens, in order to be able to handle errors should some happen.
>
> When PostgreSQL rejects the whole batch, pgloader logs the error
>   message then isolates the bad row(s) from the accepted ones by
>   retrying the batched rows in smaller batches. To do that, pgloader
>   parses the CONTEXT error message from the failed COPY, as the message
>   contains the line number where the error was found in the batch, as in
>   the following example:
>
> CONTEXT: COPY errors, line 3, column b: "2006-13-11"
>
> Using that information, pgloader will reload all rows in the batch
>   before the erroneous one, log the erroneous one as rejected, then try
>   loading the remaining of the batch in a single attempt, which may or
>   may not contain other erroneous data.
>
> At the end of a load containing rejected rows, you will find two files
>   in the root-dir location, under a directory named the same as the
>   target database of your setup. The filenames are the target table, and
>   their extensions are .dat for the rejected data and .log for the file
>   containing the full PostgreSQL client side logs about the rejected
>   data.