# Indices, Drop before Loading and Create after Loading

Tags: postgresql

1. How do you drop all indices before loading new data into an existing table, and make new indices after loading the new data ?
2. COPY command is faster than INSERT INTO right ?

Answer (score 0):

## Part 1.

Suppose you have a table `test`

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    bill integer,
    fred text,
    stamp timestamp without time zone
);
```

Add a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`

```
test=# ALTER TABLE test
ADD CONSTRAINT fred_ux UNIQUE (fred);
ALTER TABLE
```

Examine your table:

```
test=# \d test
                          Table "public.test"
 Column |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 bill   | integer                     |           |          | 
 fred   | text                        |           |          | 
 stamp  | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "fred_ux" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (fred)
```

Now, we can see that our unique constraint `fred_ux` is there.

To drop it, we simply do:

```
test=# ALTER TABLE test DROP CONSTRAINT fred_ux;
ALTER TABLE
```

Luckily, we can chain these - i.e. you can write (details [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-drop-index/))

```
ALTER TABLE xyz DROP CONSTRAINT abc, def, ghi, ......
```

Examine table test again:

```
test=# \d test
                          Table "public.test"
 Column |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 bill   | integer                     |           |          | 
 fred   | text                        |           |          | 
 stamp  | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
```

Et voilà! `fred_ux` is gone!

To restore your indices after whatever your load process is, you simply rerun the commands which created them in the first place. In order to have a record of these commands, then **BEFORE** you drop your indexes, run the command

./bin/pg_dump -s -t my_table my_schema

and pump the output to a file. In that file, you will have all the information you require to recreate that table, including any indexes, constraints &c.

## Part 2.

`COPY` is **way** quicker than using `INSERT`s. However, `COPY` has one major flaw - if there's even one dodgy record, the entire batch will fail - there's no recovery mechanism. You might want to look at [pg_loader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader) - you can find a basic outline [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/234825/postgresql-copy-fails-error-missing-data-for-column-column-name/234829#234829).